# Softban command(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So im currently working on an softban command and i want that the user gets send a new inv link per dm. But it isnt sending them a message. Thats my code. Thank you!

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def softban(ctx, user: discord.User=None):
    if user == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Softban**",
                              description=f"Softban will ban but immediately unban the user and send them a new invite link!"
                                          f"\nUsage: {prefix}softban <User>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    try:
        inv = await ctx.author.guild.create_invite(max_uses=1)
        await user.send(f"You got softbanned from {ctx.author.guild}\nJoin again with this link: {inv}")
    except:
        await ctx.send("User probably has their dms closed!")
    await ctx.guild.ban(user)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    await ctx.guild.unban(user)
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} got softbanned!")
    print(f"{user} got softbanned from {ctx.guild.name}")
```

Comment: "*But it isnt sending them one*" means what?

Comment: it isnt sending them a message per dm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some kind of logical error in your code. You have to `ban` and `unban` the user in your `try` statement. I would also consider looking at `exceptions` again and have a look on what you need.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def softban(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Softban**",
                              description=f"Softban will ban but immediately unban the user and send them a new invite link!"
                                          f"\nUsage: softban <User>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    try:
        inv = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1)
        await user.send(f"You got softbanned from {ctx.author.guild}\nJoin again with this link: {inv}")
        await ctx.guild.ban(user)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} got softbanned!")
        print(f"{user} got softbanned from {ctx.guild.name}")
    except:
        # Do whatever you want to if DMs are closed (Ban/Unban)
```

- We can only create an invite to a text-channel so we use `ctx.channel.create_invite`
- For `user` we say it has to be `discord.Member`

**The docs for that can be found here:**

- [Exceptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=except#discord.ClientException)
- [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member)
- [try/except handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: ty so much that worked for me!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If you think that is the best solution do not forget to "accept" the answer if you want to. Happy coding! :)